# vf page color setting

Tags: html, visualforce, style

I have below page code where I need to color the whole page with color code #FFFECC. Can someone please help?

Page:

```
<apex:page Controller="test_k" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >

 <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"/>  
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.ColorPicker, 'ColorPicker/js/jquery.colorPicker.js')}"  />
 <link type="text/css" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.ColorPicker, 'ColorPicker/css/colorPicker.css')}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style type="text/css">
        .custPopup{
            background-color: #e1f1f7;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-style: double;


            position: absolute;
            width: 99%;
            height: 99%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 9998;
        }
        .popupBackground{
            background-color:black;
            opacity: 0.10;
            filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 9998;
        }

        .colorPopup{
            background-color: white;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-style: double;
            z-index: 9999;
            left: 60%;
            padding:10px;
            position: absolute;
            /* These are the 3 css properties you will need to change so the popup 
            displays in the center of the screen. First set the width. Then set 
            margin-left to negative half of what the width is. You can add 
            the height property for a fixed size pop up if you want.*/

            width: 300px;

            margin-left: -250px;
            top:10px;

        }

         .headerRow .TableTitle {
            background-color: #F0F8FF !important;
            background-image: none !important; //This is needed if you want to overwrite the header background
            color: #CC0000 !important; 
            font-size:100% !important; 
          }

            .target{
    color: #b7b7b7 !important;
    background:#grey!important;
    border-color : #e7e7e7 !important;}


    .target1{
    display:block !important;}

.orange { background: #ffa500; }
.red { background: #FF0000; }
.no {background : #fbfbfb}

  .tableClass
        {
        background :green;
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 3px;
            border: 2px solid white;
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: 100%;

        }

    </style> 
<script type="text/javascript">


function cw()
{
//alert("ll");
self.close();
}

function cw1()
{

self.close();
}


window.onload=function(){
//jQuery('[id$=theSelectList]').addClass(this.options[this.selectedIndex].className)

var className =  jQuery("[id$='theSelectList'] option:first").attr('class');
 jQuery("[id$='theSelectList']").addClass(className );
 //  alert('className ' + className );
//jQuery('[id$=theSelectList]'.addClass("classname");

}


function selectNew(cmd)
{

//jQuery('[id$=k]').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('target')



if(cmd=='create')
{

createNew();
}
}


function xyz(){

jQuery('[id$=k]').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('target')

}



function getfoc()
{
jQuery('[id$=Create]').attr('disabled', 'true').addClass("target");
jQuery('input[type=text]').blur();
        jQuery('[id$=theInputText]').focus();

}


function xx(){
 var empty = false;
            if (jQuery('[id$=theInputText]').val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }

              if (empty) {

              jQuery('[id$=Create]').attr('disabled', 'true').addClass("target");

        } else {
           jQuery('[id$=Create]').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('target'); 
        }


}




  function k()
   {
     var isCreate=  jQuery("[id$='theSelectList'] option:selected").val();
  //  alert('k'+isCreate);

    if(isCreate=='<create>')
{

createNew();

}


   }

</script>
  <apex:form >

<script>
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$("[id$='color4']").colorPicker({showHexField: false});
});

j$.fn.colorPicker.defaults.colors = ['FF0000', 'ffa500'];
</script>
<h1 style="text-align:center;color:blue;background-color:#FFFECC;">
  Add to List:  </h1>
  <br/><br/>
  <apex:actionFunction name="createNew" action="{!f1}" reRender="nonepopup" oncomplete="getfoc()"/>

    <!--apex:selectList id="theSelectList" value="{!s}"  multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className"-->

     <apex:selectList id="theSelectList" value="{!s}"  multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="k()" >
      <!--apex:selectList id="theSelectList" value="{!s}"  multiselect="false" size="1"  onchange="selectNew(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"  onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className" -->



      <apex:selectOptions value="{!Matrix}"/>
    </apex:selectlist>
     <script> var entries= document.getElementById('{!$Component.theSelectList}');
      //alert('k');
     // alert(entries.value);
      for (var i = entries.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
        if (entries.options[i].text == ''){
            entries.remove(i);
        }
    }
      </script>
    <br/>

    <apex:commandButton id="k" value="OK" action="{!createandclose}" oncomplete="cw()"   />


        <apex:commandButton id="cancel" value="cancel"  oncomplete="cw()"   />  

  <apex:outputPanel id="nonepopup">

        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!popup}"/>
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!popup}" style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;" >
            <br/>

 <apex:inputText id="color4"     value="{!color}"  />
<script>
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$("[id$='color4']").colorPicker({showHexField: false});
});

j$.fn.colorPicker.defaults.colors = ['FF0000', 'ffa500'];
</script>


       <br/><br/>My List Name : 
               <apex:inputText id="theInputText" value="{!s1}" onkeyup="xx()" /><br/><br/>

                <apex:commandButton id="Create" value="Create" action="{!createandclose}" oncomplete="cw1()" rerender="nonepopup" />
                 <apex:commandButton id="cancel1" value="cancel"  oncomplete="cw()"   /> 

            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>

  </apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something here, you just need to add the following CSS:

```
body {
  background: #FFFECC !important;
}
```

I have a feeling Salesforce's default stylesheets would take priority but by adding `!important` this particular value *should* then take priority over SF's default stylings. Or, you could of course use `standardStyleSheets="false"` in your `<apex:page>` as a parameter to disable all Salesforce stylings entirely.

Comment: Where should I put the body reference? Can you please place it here?

Comment: @SFDC_Learner Within the `<style type="text/css">` tags.